# How the dispose() method works in C#.net?

Tags: c#

I am developing smart device application in C#. It is a window application. In that application I have created the 4 to 5 window form. I am navigating in these forms from one form to another form by using linklabel control in C#. In `linklabel_Click()` method which I am using to navigate I am using the code `form1.show()` according to need. I read that `form1.show()` method automatically calls the `form1.dispose()` method on the from1. I also read that once we dispose the form it is removed from memory & we can not call it again. But in my application no one form gets disposed. I can see all the form even after calling the `form1.show()` method. when I use the link to go once again to from1 it does not get disposed. Is anything wrong in my concept? I am new in C#. Please tell me how the dispose method work in above context? What is the use of dispose method. It will be better if you describe me above issue with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that form1.show() method
>   automatically calls the
>   form1.dispose()  method on the from1

That is very, very wrong. Forms behave like other objects and stay around as long as you keep a reference to them. And they stay usable until somebody/something calls Dispose().

Answer (score 0):

You can even use Finalize().

Comment: In C# you can neither call nor override Finalize

Comment: @Henk: You can override Finalize.

Comment: @Dario: No you cannot. Try it.

Comment: Much as constructors/destructors in C++, you can define `~FinalizeTest() { /* Finalizer code here */ }` to be your overridden finalizer. The `~` notation is just syntactic sugar, in VB you state `Overrides Finalize` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a reference to the frame you disposed from the alive frame? Then it will not be garbage collected.

Comment: 'Not being collected' is not the same as 'not disposed'